# HTML и JS код в одном файле

Tags: html

Чем это плохо?.
CSS файлы у меня отдельно, да, вставляются тегом style, а JS код вместе с HTML и PHP.

Comment: И ещё: PHP и HTML в одном файле - нормально же в принципе? С учётом, что практически нет каких-то элементов типа "header" или "footer" сайта, то есть почти везде идёт частично генерация HTML кода с помощью PHP. Тогда нормально?

Comment: Представим момент когда в начале идут теги html, а в центре вставка <?php ?>. Bдруг вам понадобилось использовать header(). Теперь имеем уже две вставки <?php ?>. В итоге их количество может значительно вырасти, что затруднит восприятие кода.

Comment: Ну не знаю, я же не буду сюда кидать все свои файлы, но мне кажется, что нет особого смысла выносить html код, который повторяться не будет, короче удобней так выходит)
По крайней мере, пока путаницы нет у меня и проблем.

Comment: Всем начинающим так кажется, со временем вы все поймете ^^

Comment: Ну а что делать, как то же писАть надо)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Плохо тем, что JavaScript код передаётся каждый раз ( хотя он практически не изменен ), вместо того, что-бы быть закешированым браузером.

Comment: Спасибо, я думал примерно так, но на стадии разработки проекта он меняется как раз часто. Понятно, значит надо будет после завершения большей части работ вынести в отдельные файлы.

Comment: Выводите сразу, приучайтесь к дисциплине ведения кода. Потом всплывет множество проблем с ссылками.

Comment: А на этапе разработки мне тогда приходится после каждого изменения обновлять в браузере изменённый файл :(

Comment: Не знаю я использую F5 всегда и проблем нет.

Comment: Нет, понятно, я так и делаю) Просто прихоится держать окна нескольких js/css файлов, которые сейчас меняешь, и после правок заходить в них и нажимать F5.

Comment: Ну когда проект разрастется вы увидите преимущества такого разделения.

Comment: Я понимаю, ну я же согласился так делать :)

Answer (score 1):

Если несколько HTML-файлов используют один и тот же JavaScript-файл, зачем его дублировать? Это затрудняет разработку. И увеличивает трафик при передаче страниц.

Answer (score 0):

Плохо это, наверное, для механизмов кеширования, и для восприятия кода. Но к примеру если php генерирует разный js как у меня часто бывает, то вынесение js в отдельный файл вызывает дополнительный гемор. Я бы конечно разделил все если бы знал удобный механизм. А смешивать вставки php с html, дает лишь очень мизерный прирост производительности поэтому лучше наверное делать вывод полностью в php. Хотя это больше вопрос вкуса. 
Собственно надо делить js на статический и динамический. Статический обязательно размещать снаружи.

Comment: "Я бы конечно разделил все если бы знал удобный механизм. А смешивать вставки php с html, дает лишь очень мизерный прирост производительности поэтому лучше наверное делать вывод полностью в php."
У меня как раз так выходит.